# What do you do about running out of ammo in Borderlands?

Tags: borderlands

While playing Borderlands I have noticed that whenever there is a boss mission you generally have to go through an entire Sahara desert to reach him in his hideout. Along the way you have to kill everyone present. This is insane. The problem:

1) There is no option to buy more ammo once you are near the boss, so either you have to switch to a different gun or come back to start all the way to buy the ammo. Using a different gun isn't an efficient method because I'll be wasting the proficiency gain which I could use on my preferred weapon.

2) When I tried coming back all the way to the beginning, the game respawns all the monsters, so I had to kill them ALL while coming back. The reward chests, however, do not respawn.

3) I purchased ammo and started running towards the boss again but to my surprise the stupid monsters had respawned yet again.

4) This time I kept rushing forward but just near the boss I was surrounded and died. I went back to the starting point again.

I'm finding this extremely frustrating. How do I proceed in this area without resorting to cheats? The mission is Sledge: Battle For Badlands.

Thanks a load in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I haven't played the game in a while, but if I remember correctly, enemies drop ammo fairly frequently.  If it's not the right kind of ammo for the gun you're using, consider switching up guns.  I remember I carried guns of 3 or 4 different classes with me at all times.  You may not be as proficient with all of them, but at least you have something to use.

Use the guns you're worse with or that the enemies are dropping ammo for against the grunt enemies, and save the really powerful guns for the boss.

Answer (score 11):

It sounds like it's time for an ammo SDU purchase.  Although not as cost effective as waiting for the large SDUs to become available, buying one now can help ensure that you'll have enough ammo when you need it.  As Brisbe said, ammo regen is your friend.  Find a class mod, skill, or even some weapons or shields with good ammo regen, and you'll never have to pick up ammo again, let alone buy it.

Comment: I finished the entire game finally and till now I didn't come accross a single ammo regen item. I checked the loot dropped and the vending machines.

Comment: Class mods are the usual suspects for ammo regen, however they don't offer as high rates as some weapons, like my Double Anarchy, which can regen ammo almost as fast as I use it.

Answer (score 7):

Class mods can also be your friend--depending on the character you choose, there should be at least one class mod that can give you ammo regen over time.  Roland (the soldier) is the best at this, but most characters have at least one ability they can use to get more ammo.  This could help you here, and overall.

Comment: Thanks I'll be on the lookout for this. Ive taken lilith (one with phazewalk ability).

Comment: Definitely for solo play the Soldier rocks due to the Ammo Regen ability/mod you can equip.

Answer (score 6):

I haven't advanced very far yet, but up to this point, I've always kept the best weapon I could find for each class around. I'm also using them fairly evenly, so my proficiency in all classes is about the same.

That way, my 'useful' ammo is the sum of the ammo I'm carrying around for all classes. Together with the ammo drops from monsters, running out of ammo is pretty much impossible. In fact, they drop so much that I'm usually full in all but the weapon I'm currently using.

And then there's the ammo upgrades (so far, I know about two levels of upgrades, I guess there are more), but I assume you know about and have these -- at least for your favorite weapon.

Answer (score 4):

Are you underleveled?  You might be running out of ammo simply because you're doing less damage.  Generally mobs in Borderlands primarily drop ammo for the types of weapons you have equipped.

Comment: Good point. But we need a good way to level up. We can probably keep trying/dying in the process described in the question and we'll also level up that way I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Roland's Scorpio turret can be upgraded to provide ammo regeneration and/or provide supply packs (which replenish ammo and grenades).

Comment: Thanks for telling me about this. In my playthrough I didn't really come accross anything about ammo regeneration though it would be fun to come accross.