# Are there weapons which regenerate ammo?

Tags: borderlands-2

In Borderlands 1 I had a great pistol which only had a 2-shot clip but reloaded almost instantly and it also regenerated ammunition over time, fast enough that it basically had infinite ammo. I haven't found a gun in BL2 that has this ability, are there any? I'm playing as Commando and I've noticed Gunzerker class mods that seem to grant this ability, but I was hoping there are weapons that do it too. The need to stop questing and go searching through containers for ammo or find an ammo vending machine is a little annoying.

Comment: Tangentially related: [my answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/13504/1351) for a BL1 question about ammo.  Hope it's a similar situation for BL2

Comment: I saw someone on the Gearbox forums talking about something called a Vladof Infinity with a magazine size of 1, but never needs reloading.

Comment: Thanks. This issue is actually detracting a bit from my enjoyment of the game, sometimes in monster-infested areas it seems like I have to detour for ammo several times before I even get to any of the mission objectives. And I can go from fully loaded with ammo to totally empty on a couple different weapon types during boss fights. The Caustic Caverns were a huge pain, with (as far as I know) no ammo machine except at the entrance.

Comment: As noted by the asker, there is a GunZerker class mod with Team Ammo regen.  Yes - it is just as game breaking as ammo regen was in BL1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Weapons that REGENERATE ammo

Note, the following two weapons require a purchase of the [Ultimate Vault Hunter Upgrade pack](http://www.borderlands2.com/vaulthunterpack/)

**[Avenger](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Avenger_(Borderlands_2))**

> *Counterbution revengence. The reckoning.* – High overall stats. Behaves like a bouncing betty grenade when reloaded. **Regenerates SMG
>   ammo when wielded**.

**[Butcher](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Butcher_(Borderlands_2))**

> *Fresh Meat!* – Very low pellet count. Greatly increased fire rate. Achieves maximum accuracy much more quickly than other Hyperion
>   shotguns. Magazine **randomly refills a random amount of ammo as it's
>   fired**, giving it a wildly variable magazine size in use. Fire rate
>   highly increases under sustained fire.

## Grenade Mods that REGENERATE ammo

The following 4 mods will require purchase of the DLC, Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragonkeep

**[Lightning Bolt](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Lightning_Bolt)**

> *What's a jigawatt?*  – Always Shock. **Regenerates grenade ammo over
>   time**. Shoots straight forward with a lightning graphic and explodes on
>   impact. Character may shout "Lightning Bolt!" and a custom throwing
>   sound will be heard after use while playing in Tiny Tina's Assault on
>   Dragon Keep.

**[Chain Lightning](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Chain_Lightning)**

> *Don't pay it back, pay it forward.* – Always Shock. **Regenerates grenade
>   ammo over time**. Shoots a bolt of lightning straight forward that
>   explodes on impact and arcs to nearby targets. Character may shout
>   "Lightning Bolt!" after use while playing in Tiny Tina's Assault on
>   Dragon Keep.

**[Fireball](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Fireball)**

> *Porkchop Sandwiches!* – Always incendiary. **Regenerates grenade ammo
>   over time.** Shoots a slow moving fireball straight forward that
>   explodes on impact. When used, has a custom sound effect when thrown
>   and the character may shout "fireball!" while in the DLC [Tiny Tina's
>   Assault on Dragon Keep.](http://borderlands2.com/dragonkeep/agegate.html)

**[Fire Storm](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Fire_Storm)**

> *What manner of man are you that can summon up fire without flint or
>   tinder?* – Always incendiary. **Regenerates grenade ammo over time.**
>   Shoots a fireball straight forward that explodes on impact. Four
>   additional fireballs spawn above the spot of the original explosion
>   and fall to the ground. Character may shout "Fireball!" upon use while
>   playing in Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep.

**[Magic Missile](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Magic_Missile)**

> *No wand required. Just point and shoot.* – Always slag. **Grenades slowly
>   regenerate over time.** Two (Blue rarity) or Four (Purple rarity) child
>   grenades home in on targets and explode instantly. Character may shout
>   "Magic Missile!" after use while playing in Tiny Tina's Assault on
>   Dragon Keep.

## Weapons that DON'T consume any ammo

**[Infinity](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Infinity):**

> *It's closer than you think! (no it isn't)* – **Does not consume ammunition**. Shots fired form a fixed lemniscate (∞) pattern,
>   ignoring normal recoil behavior. Increased accuracy when aiming down
>   the sights.

As an extra note, you'll need to have at least 1 bullet of pistol ammo, or the Infinity will not fire.

**[Some Vladof launchers:](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Vladof)**

> Vladof launchers can have the special ability "*reduced ammo
>   consumption*," which means that **every third shot fired is not
>   deducted from either the magazine or the player's ammo stock.** This
>   is coupled with lower base damage, though the overall destructive
>   capacity of the weapon remains roughly the same as an equivalent
>   launcher from most other manufacturers.

Comment: Link to the wiki page?

Answer (score 5):

**Near as I can tell, no there are no guns with ammo regen.**

A quick Google search turns up many [similar threads](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/638784-borderlands-2/64099723), obviously people are missing it from Borderlands 1.  Some alternatives:

- Play the Gunzerker.  He has class mods for personal and team ammo regen, and the "Gunzerking" class ability, which regenerates ammo for all of his guns (unlocked very early).  Gunzerker also has class skills for increasing ammo capacity.  ***Play this guy, and you'll never have an ammo problem*** (in my experience).
- Apparently certain shields exist which "capture" bullets that are shot at (and hit) you.
- [Use Eridium](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85388/where-can-i-spend-eridium) to expand your ammo capacity for your favorite guns.

Answer (score 3):

The [Butcher](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Butcher_%28Borderlands_2%29) pearlescent shotgun has an indirect type of ammo regeneration. Special weapon effects from Borderlands wiki (emphasis mine):

> Fresh Meat! – Very low pellet count. Greatly increased fire rate. Achieves maximum accuracy much more quickly than other Hyperion shotguns. **Magazine randomly refills a random amount of ammo as it's fired**, giving it a wildly variable magazine size in use. Fire rate increases under sustained fire.
>
> Note: The ammo refilled is not removed from the character ammo stock, so it can be considered as an indirect type of ammo regeneration.

Items that can regenerate, add ammo or give more ammo capacity:

- The [Hoarder](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Hoarder) Class Mods for the Gunzerker / Salvador, which gives team ammo regeneration
- [Absorb Shields](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Absorb_Shield) have a set percentage chance of adding ammunition to the user's reserves when struck with a bullet or rocket-based attack. The Absorb Shield with the highest percentage chance of absorbing enemy bullets or rockets is [The Sham](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/The_Sham) (highest possible absorb chance is 94%).
- [Stockpile Relic](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Stockpile_Relic) or a [Blood of the Ancients](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Blood_of_the_Ancients) relic - boosts the maximum amount of ammunition the wielder can carry
- [Ammo Shrines](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/121904/4797), introduced in the 'Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep' DLC allow you to quickly regenerate ammo.

Comment: The butcher + psycho with bloodlust = tons of fun